# VBA Overflow Error 6 -- simply when terminating a class

Tags: vba, overflow

I am trying to debug code that typically functions properly and has been in production for a while, but has some errors associated with particular case runs.

I have a class called "Guarantee", and a variable / object, "myDem", which is of that class.  The class has an associated function called "NumberOfGuaranteeDays".  The first image given below shows a Long variable called "numRows" being assigned to this function call on "myDem".  When this assigment is made -- and, therefore, the "NumberOfGuaranteeDays" function is called -- I receive an Overflow error.

[image: Higher level function call causing the root overflow error. Note that "numRows" is a Long variable.]

After the function call "NumberOfGuaranteeDays" is run, which is a fairly complex call with many sub-functions itself, then class attempts to terminate itself, and return the value (the number of days, which is an integer... in this case it's 32561).  It is during this termination step and the assignment of "numRows" to the value 32561, when the error occurs.

[image: Termination of the class call. The last step that works before the overflow error message is returned.]

Here I simply demonstrate that the very next step within the code, if I step through it, is where the error message is returned back to me.

[image: Error message, seen immediately after the termination subroutine completes]

Finally I wanted to provide "proof" that the value assigned to "numRows" is 32561, of type Integer, which can acceptably be assigned to a Long.  Note in the far right in the watch part of the window, the value "res" is the value which is returned from the "NumberOfGuaranteeDays" call, which is then assigned to the variable "numRows".

[image: Look far to the right in the watch portion of the window for the value of "res". This gets assigned to "numRows", where the crash occurs.]

As far as I can tell, there are only 2 possibilities for why a crash can be occurring:

1. There is an error in the attempt to terminate the class.  I don't understand how this could lead to an "overflow" error, though.
2. There is an error in the assignment of the value calculated from "NumberOfGuaranteeDays" to the variable "numRows".  This sort of assignment could potentially have an overflow, but not in this case.  The return from "NumberOfGuaranteeDays", which is the "res" integer set at 32561, is assigned to "numRows", which is a Long.

So, since neither of these possibilities that I can imagine make sense, I figure there must be another possibility I cannot see.  Thank you all in advance for the help!

I opted to put in cut & pasted images instead of writing as code because so much of what's critical to understanding the steps is seeing "proof" of where I am in the debugging stages.  If actual code snippets would help, let me know.

```
        Thank you!
               Mike
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa164754(v=office.10).aspx

Comment: Have you tried removing that line and not manually clearing it? Same error?

Comment: @enderland Which line?  The final line that is setting the local variable back to nothing?  I can, but how could setting a value to nothing ever cause an overflow.  If you mean the original line that calls the class function, yes, I have.  The script moves onward, but without calculating this value, numRows, which I need in later work.

Comment: @jbabey Sorry, I don't understand your point.  Of course I looked at the definition of these types, hence the elaborate explanation in my OP where I explained that I am assigning to a LONG a value of only ~ 33,000.